# Nested for loops in python for Ising Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics, enumeration

Im working on statistical mechanics currently, and trying to apply some programming to it since they fit so well together! Im working on finding the partition function for a finite number of particles. However..the partition function is defined as a sum of a sum! I guess we could write this as a list of a list, so we would use nested for-loops, but i just cant quite figure out the correct way of writing it.

Z=\sum_{s_1}^{s_N}e^(s_1s_2+...+s_(N-1)s_N)  is the partition function.

[image]

the possible values of s_i are -1,+1.

Effectively the ising model(1D) is a chain with N points on it and each point can have s_i=-1 or +1. The energy of the system depends on the values of s_i, and each possible combination is called a state. the total sum of these states is called Z, the partition fucntion.

So for a chain of length N=5(hence 2^5=32 possible states) how would i calculate this Z? I dont really have any code to show, but i know from the formula the result should be something like e^(+1+1+1+1+1)+e^(-1+1+1+1+1)+...+e^(-1-1-1-1-1).  The question is..how on earth do I go about doing that? Ive generate the set of possible states:

```
import itertools
counting=0
for state in itertools.product([1,-1],repeat=5):
    print(state)
    counting+=1
print('the total possible number of states is',counting).
```

but how can i use this to get to a value for Z?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a function to calculate the sum for each state, then do the overall sum afterwards:

```
import itertools
from math import exp

def each_state(products):
     for state in products:
         yield sum(state)


Z = sum(exp(x) for x in each_state(itertools.product([1,-1],repeat=5)))
```

The benefit of this approach is that it is in keeping with the spirit of `itertools`: to not aggregate everything into memory at once. So while a `numpy` solution might be faster, say you wanted to calculate `Z` for many states, a `numpy` implementation would start to hit memory issues whereas the generator expression will not:

```py
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
from math import exp

# this will yield a single number, and product will yield
# each state one at a time, never aggregating the
# full set of objects into memory (even though it might seem slow)
x = sum(exp(sum(x)) for x in product([1,-1], repeat=500))


# On my 16GB MacBook, this process will be killed because
# we collect all of the states into memory
x = np.array(list(product([1, -1], repeat=500))
[1]    7743 killed     python
```

The general rule of thumb is that `list(giant_iterable)` runs out of space whereas `for item in giant_iterable` will run out of time

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the problem, you can calculate it using `numpy` as follows:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

states = np.array([state for state in itertools.product([1,-1], repeat=5)])
print("There are %d states" % states.shape[0])  # 32 states

# calculate the sum for each state
sum_over_each_state = np.sum(states, axis=1)  
print(sum_over_each_state)

# calculate e^(sum(state)) for each state
exp_of_all_states = np.exp(sum_over_each_state)
print(exp_of_all_states)

# sum up all exponentials
Z = np.sum(exp_of_all_states)
print("Z:", Z)
```

This gives `Z = 279.96`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it makes a lot of sense to do it this way. i dont understand the sum over each state part though..this should have N-1 terms, not the N terms determined by states..
also what do you mean by youre not sure if its the right z? what z do you think i should seek?

Comment: I wrote that to clarify that I just used your description and did not look up whether what I calculate is the quantity you're after. I clarified the wording, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I thought you want to sum over e^(-1-1-1-1-1) to e^(+1+1+1+1+1)? `sum_over_each_state` calculates the sum for each of the `N = 32` states generated (resulting in values between -5 and 5), each of which is then used as an exponent. I split up the calculation to make it easier to follow.